# Nginx 502 in Administrator

Tags: joomla-3.x, nginx

I just transferred my Joomla installation to DigitalOcean and i'm running on nginx. Site seems to be running fine but when I login to the administrator portion and try to update something in the global configuration i get the following error:

```
2014/06/26 10:08:38 [error] 19654#0: *1035 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:
file_put_contents(/usr/share/nginx/projects/hoopsforu/configuration.php): failed to open stream
: Permission denied in /usr/share/nginx/projects/hoopsforu/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php
 on line 426" while reading response header from upstream, client: 70.208.86.53, server: hoopsf
oru.com, request: "POST /administrator/index.php?option=com_config HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcg
i://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "hoopsforu.com", referrer: "http://hoopsforu.com/administrator/index
.php?option=com_config"
2014/06/26 10:08:38 [error] 19654#0: *1035 upstream sent invalid status "0 Could not write to t
he configuration file" while reading response header from upstream, client: 70.208.86.53, serve
r: hoopsforu.com, request: "POST /administrator/index.php?option=com_config HTTP/1.1", upstream
: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "hoopsforu.com", referrer: "http://hoopsforu.com/administra
tor/index.php?option=com_config"
```

This is what my config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  hoopsforu.com www.hoopsforu.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root           /usr/share/nginx/projects/hoopsforu;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
        # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
        location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                        return 403;
                        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

        # caching of files
        location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                        expires 1y;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                        expires 14d;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are your directory permissions correct? It looks like a directory permissions error.  it should be 644 and 755 for files and folders respectively, per this awnser : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/133/19

Comment: @ContextSwitch I changed all permissions as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817767/1086938 and still the same issue.

Comment: Can it be the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: no, nginx doesn't use the .htacess file, that's only apahce.

Comment: I'm not sure what user nginx uses (apache was apache) but check to make sure that the configuration.php's owner or grougp is set to that user or that user's group

Comment: @ContextSwitch Cool that did it. I switched the folder to nginx:nginx. Thanks a lot. Feel free submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your permissions are set to 644 and 755 for files and folders respectively. More on permissions can be found here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/133/19

Also make sure the user or group is set to nginx so that nginx has permission to write to those files / directories.